# Getting hikvision IP camera video in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ip, ip-camera

I have a very not easy task. I want to get my IP camera's video to unity. I have no idea how to do that. It would be great if someone will point a finger at a direction that I should go.

I have tried web browser package for unity for to view hikvision camera's data in browser you need IE engine (activex and such stuff).

I have also tried IP camera package from GitHub. It simply doesn't work.

Are there any algorithm or maybe even a firmware that I could use to get the video data?

Thank you

Comment: you can stream the live video by using the VLC media player check https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the link, but I couldn't use it. Still, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to do this but I will have to get frames as jpg using [code in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398958/grabbing-frames-from-a-hikvision-ip-camera?rq=1) question's answer. It will be bad for performance but for now it's ok