# Unity bitmaps implementation for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bitmap

Hope you doing fine! I want to use bitmaps in my c# code in unity. But I can't implement bitmaps onto my code, because System.Drawing doesn't work in unity. Also my project is for android devices so I am looking for a solution for android. I couldn't find any  useful stuff on the web. even if i did, i didn't understand. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use jpg or png in unity, isn't that enough?

Comment: @shingo yes I know that. I am just trying to make code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398958/grabbing-frames-from-a-hikvision-ip-camera?rq=1 to work

Comment: See following : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory#:~:text=bitmap%20is%20no%20longer%20being%20used.%20If%20you,counting%20%28in%20the%20variables%20mDisplayRefCountand%20mCacheRefCount%29%20to%20track

Comment: Sorry for late response! Thanks a lot! That's what I have been looking for. But somehow I couldn't find it. Maybe I'm a bad researcher. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jdweng for the link! It is
android.graphics.bitmap